# PHP try, catch precedence and inheritance

Tags: php

I'm wondering about something regarding PHP's `try`, `catch` statements.

Let's consider the following example.

```php
abstract class ExceptionA extends Exception
{}

class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA
{}

class ExceptionTest
{
    public function example()
    {
        try {
            throw new ExceptionB();
        } catch ( ExceptionB $e ) {
            echo 'ExceptionB was caught';
        } catch ( ExceptionA $e ) {
            echo 'ExceptionA was caught';
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo 'Exception was caught';
        }
    }
}
```

All `catch` statements match the exception. Where the first (`ExceptionB`) is the closest match.

Will the order of the `catch` statements be of influence to which one will catch it?

Comment: It may seem obvious after reading the answer/manual, but I think it's important to note that the order of catch blocks in your example is really the only valid order for that set of exceptions. In any other order at least one of the catch blocks would be unreachable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch):

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be
>   executed, and PHP will attempt to find the **first matching catch block**.

You can easily confirm it:

### Catching `ExceptionB` first:

```
class ExceptionTest
{
    public function example()
    {
        try {
            throw new ExceptionB();
        } catch (ExceptionB $e) {
            echo 'ExceptionB was caught';
        } catch (ExceptionA $e) {
            echo 'ExceptionA was caught';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception was caught';
        }
    }
}

(new ExceptionTest())->example();  // Exception B was caught
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/htgEg**

### Catching `ExceptionA` first and `ExceptionB` after:

```
class ExceptionTest
{
    public function example()
    {
        try {
            throw new ExceptionB();
        } catch (ExceptionA $e) {
            echo 'ExceptionA was caught';
        } catch (ExceptionB $e) {
            echo 'ExceptionB was caught';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception was caught';
        }
    }
}

(new ExceptionTest())->example();  // Exception A was caught
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/J7Xul**